# Probabilities for ending letters in words?

Tags: matlab

I have a text file of around 9000 lowercase words. I want to find the probabilities for the last letters in each word (frequency of letter/number of words).

Here's my first go:

```
function [ prma ] = problast()
counts = zeros(1,26);
%refer to cell index here to get alphabetic number of char
s = regexp('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz','.','match');
f = fopen('nouns.txt');
ns = textscan(f,'%s');
fclose(f);
%8960 is the length of the file 
for i =1:8960
 c = substr(ns(i),-1,1);
 num = find(s == c);
 counts(num) = num;
end
prma = counts / 8960;
disp(prma);
```

This gives me this error:

```
Undefined function 'substr' for input arguments of type 'cell'.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, you don't need `regexp` for your problem. A very simple and efficient solution to your problem would be:

```
clear;
close;
clc;

counts = zeros(1,26);

f = fopen('nouns.txt');
ns = textscan(f,'%s');
fclose(f);

for i =1:numel(ns{1})
    c = ns{1}{i}(end);
    counts('c'-96) = counts('c'-96)+1;
end

prma = counts / numel(ns{1});
disp(prma);
```

For example, if `"noun.txt"` were to contain

```
paris
london
```

the output would be:

```
  Columns 1 through 8

         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0

  Columns 9 through 16

         0         0         0         0         0    0.5000         0         0

  Columns 17 through 24

         0         0    0.5000         0         0         0         0         0

  Columns 25 through 26

         0         0
```

Comment: One can argue about efficiency using a for loop. You can use a histogram instead (see Shai's solution).

Answer (score 2):

The [`textscan`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) documentation states that the result is a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html).  If you're not familiar with cell arrays I highly suggest you read the link I've given, but the long and short of it is that your code should look like this:

```
c = substr(ns{i},-1,1);
```

Note the change from `(` `)` to `{` `}` - this is how cell array elements are accessed.

Comment: I changed the parentheses to curly braces but I'm getting the same error as above. Am I doing something else wrong?

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
f = fopen('nouns.txt');
ns = textscan(f, '%s');
fclose(f);

num = cellfun(@(x)(x(end) - 'a' + 1), ns{:}); %// Convert to 1-26
counts = hist(num, 1:26);                     %// Count occurrences
prob = counts / numel(ns{:})                  %// Compute probabilities
```

Comment: `textscan` already tokenizes words, why use `regexp` for that? Also, I think you need `[^a-z]*` and not `[^a-z]` in the pattern...

Comment: Oh, and I believe it should `x(end)` instead of `x(1)`, because the question asks for the probabilities of the letter in the word, not the first. I've taken the liberty to amend your solution...

Comment: @EitanTit was `x(1)` when I used `regexp` to take only the lase letter

Comment: Ah, I see. But if so, then you don't really need the index (`x` should suffice). Anyway, +1 for the histogram solution, I was just about to suggest it myself when you posted it, this is the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is causing the problem, but this should do the trick, assuming that `ns{i}` contains your string:

```
str = ns{i}; 
c = str(end);
```

If this does not work it should not be too hard to play around a bit and create the variable `str` based on `ns`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions everyone, I solved this on my own but I went back and tried the last answer and it worked perfectly. Here's what I came up with:

```
%Keep track of counts
counts = zeros(1,26);
%Refer to this array to get alphabetic numeric value of character
s = regexp('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz','.','match');
f = fopen('nouns.txt');
ns = textscan(f,'%s');
fclose(f);
%8960 = length of nouns.txt
for i =1:8960
    %string from vs
    str = ns{1}{i};
    %last character in that string
    c = str(length(str));
    %index in s
    temp = strfind(s,c);
    index = find(not(cellfun('isempty',temp)));
    counts(index) = counts(index)+1;
 end

%Get probabilities
prma = counts / 8960;
disp(prma);
```

I voted everyone up for helping me brainstorm.